# EXC_BAD_ACCESS scrolling TableView

Tags: objective-c, ios

im getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when i scroll my TableView. I heard something like alloc being called wrong, I dont know. Here's my code:

```
        -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            return [[resultsDictionary objectForKey: @"bills"] count];
        }

        - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
                 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            // Identifier for retrieving reusable cells.
            static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"MyCellIdentifier";

            // Attempt to request the reusable cell.
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

            // No cell available - create one.
            if(cell == nil) {
                cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                              reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
            }


            NSArray *billsArray = [resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"bills"];

            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[billsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];

            return cell;
        }
```

**EDIT**

I think the error is here:

*** -[JKArray objectAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6a5d030

```
NSString *cellName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[billsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"]];
```

Comment: Do you have a call stack in the debugger?  What line of code does it point to?

Comment: This one:  NSArray *billsArray = [resultsDictionary objectForKey:@"bills"];

Comment: If you're not using ARC don't forget to autorelease cell after you alloc/init

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `resultsDictionary` is a dangling pointer.  If you are using ARC, you need a strong reference to it somewhere.  If you are not using ARC, you need to retain it somewhere.

Comment: Looks like is something with the cell, I trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. My billsArray was missing 'self' instance, as inside of cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Thanks to everyone.